# Division in natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than $1$. Show that there exists an integer $m$ greater than $n^n$ such that $(n^m-m^n)/(n+m)$ is an integer.

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: This question was featured on the Serbian mathematics Olympiad,http://srb.imomath.com/zadaci/2016_smo.pdf it's the first one,but the olympiad is finished.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $n^m-m^n\equiv n^m+(-1)^{n+1}n^n$

> **Hint 2.** Try $m=a\cdot n^n-n$

${}$

> Let $m=an^n-n$. We want $a\mid n^{m-n}+(-1)^{n+1}$. If $n$ is odd, we can take $a=2$. If $n>2$ is even, we can take any divisor of $n-1$ for $a$ (e.g. $n-1$).
>  Note that $(n-1)n^n-n>n^n$ for $n>2$.
>  If $n=2$, we can take $m=5$.